# Tomcat Security Constraint not working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

After adding https support for tomcat. I am not able to run the application

My web.xml config

```xml
<display-name>EBaySignin</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>credentials.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

(Tomcat)server.xml config:

```xml
  <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->

    <Connector port="8443"  SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="/Users/ArunAbraham/.keystore" keystorePass="password"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Now i am unable to access the app, i get an error: Cannot connect to server. What could i be missing ? `("https://localhost:8443/EBaySignin/")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that could be wrong.
Also be more specific about the error and check the server-logs.
Possible problems:

1. Check path, password and contents of the keystore file.
   It needs an SSL entry that identifies the server by matching host-name.
2. Remove initially the "web.xml" security constraints.
   Get SSL working first on port 8443, then add that back in after SSL is working.
3. Make sure the client can reach the server over the network on port 8443.
4. Go back through each point on the Tomcat SSL setup.
   I have used this many times and it works.
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: I did check without the <security-constraint> declaration, the SSL works fine. But once i add the <security-constraint> declaration, none of the apps work. Even the non secure ones dont work. It just gives http 404 error.

Comment: I am able to access this https://localhost:8443 but i can't access the web app, i get server not found error (404).

Comment: Okay, so SSL is not the problem. So now to the security-constraints. Again, check the basic docs on how to implement but check the URL pattern for the conditions in the "web.xml" and if using, for example, role-based security, that the security-role name is matching up with what is setup on the receiving side. Remember that the <security-constraint> element is preventing unauthorized users from getting into the application so they have to be authorized (user/password), their roles, checked, etc.